# pythonで2つのcsvファイルを比較し重複している値を抽出する

Tags: python, pandas, csv

2つのcsvファイルを比較して、両ファイル内に重複している内容で抽出する方法を考えており
適切なコードがわからず、御教授願います。

(py勉強中のため、web・本等のプログラム内容を無理やりな方法で作成しております。不備はご容赦下さい)

データーの読み込み・データーフレーム迄の形はできたのですが
これより先の、データフレームを使用してデータの抽出プログラム方法がわからず御教授お願い致します。
(データ数量は、今回抜粋しておりますが両csvファイルとも実際は約50万件ほどのデータです)

**下記内容が、比較データになります。**

```
CRcode  client name & address1(TDｸﾗｲｱﾝﾄ0213 csvﾃﾞｰﾀ)
598     株式会社日医ﾘｰｽ,東京都品川区西五反田1-3-8五反田御幸ﾋﾞﾙ4F
2598    株式会社ﾌﾗﾜｰｵｰｸｼｮﾝｼﾞｬﾊﾟﾝ,東京都大田区東海2-2-1大田市場花き部
341     株式会社 大成紙工,
796     ｾﾝｺｰ引越 株式会社,

CRcode1 client name & address2(検証14csvﾃﾞｰﾀ)
200 　　株式会社日医ﾘｰｽ,東京都品川区西五反田1-3-8五反田御幸ﾋﾞﾙ4F
4500    大成紙工株式会社,群馬県北群馬郡吉岡町上野田1329
```

**抽出したいデータ内容(上記内容より重複している結果のイメージを抽出したい内容です)**

```
598 　株式会社日医ﾘｰｽ,東京都品川区西五反田1-3-8五反田御幸ﾋﾞﾙ4F
```

(下記が書きましたpyコードです)

```
### 両ファイル比較検証 ###
#ライブラリー呼び出し
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import pathlib as path

#CSVファイル読み込み
path_ip = path.WindowsPath(r"c:\Users\Desktop\ファイル比較検証\TDクライアント0213.csv") 
t1 = pd.read_csv(path_ip, engine="python")
t1['CRcode'] = t1['CRcode'].astype(str).str.zfill(8)
t1['client name & address1'] = t1['client name & address1'].astype(str)

#CSVファイル読み込み
path_ip = path.WindowsPath(r"c:\Users\Desktop\ファイル比較検証\検証14.csv") 
t2 = pd.read_csv(path_ip, engine="python")
t2['CRcode1'] = t2['CRcode1'].astype(str).str.zfill(9)
t2['client name & address2'] = t2['client name & address2'].astype(str)

#deta 抽出
t1 = pd.DataFrame({'CRcode': t1['CRcode'],
                  'client name & address1': t1['client name & address1']},
                  columns = ['CRcode','client name & address1'])
#deta 抽出
t2 = pd.DataFrame({'CRcode1': t2['CRcode1'],
                  'client name & address2': t2['client name & address2']},
                  columns = ['CRcode1','client name & address2'])
```

Comment: 掲示の CSV データですが、CRcode  と client name & ... カラムの間がタブかスペースになっているのと、ヘッダ部分にはカンマ(`,`)が含まれていないので、`pd.read_csv()` で読み込むと、`t1['CRcode']` などが key error になってしまいます。CSV データを写し間違えていませんか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ベストではないと思いますが、こんな感じでどうでしょうか。

```
#deta 抽出
t1 = pd.DataFrame({'CRcode': t1['CRcode'],
                  'client name & address1': t1['client name & address1']},
                  columns = ['CRcode','client name & address'])
#deta 抽出
t2 = pd.DataFrame({'CRcode1': t2['CRcode1'],
                  'client name & address2': t2['client name & address2']},
                  columns = ['CRcode1','client name & address'])

n = len(t1)
mask = pd.concat([t1, t2]).duplicated(subset='client name & address', keep=False)[:n]
# t1[mask]
t1[mask].drop_duplicates(subset='client name & address')
```

Comment: dkatoさん　御教授ありがとうございます。　問題が1点ありました。　下名のミスで、t1内にも同じ会社名・同じ住所の案件があり２件・3件と同じ

Comment: `.drop_duplicate(subset='client name & address')`で対応できるかもしれません。

Comment: dkatoさん　　　pyｺｰﾄﾞの件、無事進みました。ありがとうございますす。　御教授頂きました件にて、1件ご報告あります。　当初、御教授頂きましたｺｰﾄﾞを入れましたが、エラーが発生。　なやんだ結果と構文を確認したところ、duplicateの最後にsが抜けていました。　　教えて頂いている立場でご報告するのも変ですが、大変申し訳ありません。　今後いろいろな案件、御教授頂くかと思いますが、宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: duplicatesのタイポ修正しました。どうも失礼いたしました。

Comment: dkatoさん　修正ありがとうございます。　下名のご報告させて頂きました案件で重複を消した物が再度復活している状況が発生しました。おそらくですが最後の　t1[mask].drop_duplicates(subset='client name & address')実施時に元のt1ﾃﾞｰﾀを読みにいっているようです。　このようにpyｺｰﾄﾞを変更させて頂きました。　　t1.drop_duplicates(subset='client name & address',inplace=True)
n = len(t1)
mask = pd.concat([t1,t2]).duplicated(subset='client name & address', keep=False)[:n]
t1[mask]　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　　簡単な比較ﾃﾞｰﾀで実施を行い確認を実施しましたが、問題等あれば　ご教授願います。